# ¿Como eliminar un boton usando win32APIS en c?

Tags: c, botón, winapi, windows7

Tengo un boton en la ventana principal, y se me vino la pregunta: `¿Como hago para eliminar ese mismo boton en tiempo de ejecucción`. He pensado llamar a la funcion: `SendDlgItemMessage`:

```C
#include <windows.h>
#define ID_BUTTON 119
...
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure( HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARA wParam,LPARAM lParam ){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow("button","Click Me for deleted mi.",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,200,200,40,20,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_BUTTON,NULL,0 );
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch( wParam ){
                case ID_BUTTON:
                    SendDlgItemMessage( hwnd,ID_BUTTON,WM_DESTROY,0,0);
                break;
            }
            break;
...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como el boton realmente es una ventana decidí en enviarle el mensage `WM_DESTROY` para que se cerrará, pero al hacer click no me lo cierra y tampoco desaparece. He comprobado que si llama la funcion  `SendDlgItemMessage` con un simple `MessageBox`.
No he conseguido como hacerlo en internet, solo me sale: `¿Como crear un boton con win32Apis?` , pero yo lo que quiero es cerrarlo, no crearlo.

#### ¿Como cierro el boton? o ¿Como lo eliminó?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función [`DestroyWindow(hWnd)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) eliminas el botón

```
//..
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch( wParam ){
        case ID_BUTTON:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    break;
//..
```

Si quieres deshabilitarlo usa la función [`EnableWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow)

```
EnableWindow(hwnd, TRUE);  // <-- TRUE para habilitar 
EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE); // <-- FALSE para deshabilitar
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: me alegra que te haya funcionado!